# XAML resouce dictionary - unable to apply default style

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm currently facing a really odd situation.

I have a WPF application with the following lines inside **App.xaml**:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary>
                <local:AppBootstrapper x:Key="bootstrapper" />
            </ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="./Styles/MyTheme.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

Then I have some dictionaries in **MyTheme.xaml**:

```
<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="./UserControlStyles.xaml"/>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="./WizardStyle.xaml"/>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf;component/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.Dark.xaml" />
    <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf;component/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.Defaults.xaml" />
    <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignColors;component/Themes/Recommended/Primary/MaterialDesignColor.Blue.xaml" />
    <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignColors;component/Themes/Recommended/Accent/MaterialDesignColor.Blue.xaml" />

    <ResourceDictionary Source="./DataGridStyles.xaml"/>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="./TreeViewStyles.xaml"/>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="./ToggleButtonStyles.xaml"/>
</ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
```

Finally there is a DataGrid that I want to apply to all DataGrids of my application by default (in **DataGridStyles.xaml**):

```
<ResourceDictionary>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGrid}" BasedOn="{StaticResource MaterialDesignDataGrid}">
            <Setter Property="AutoGenerateColumns" Value="False" />
            <Setter Property="CanUserAddRows" Value="False" />
            <Setter Property="CanUserDeleteRows" Value="False" />
            <Setter Property="SelectionMode" Value="Single" />
        </Style>
    </ResourceDictionary>
```

The DataGrid style is not applying for some reason, but it works if I put it directly inside **MyTheme.xaml**:

```
<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="./UserControlStyles.xaml"/>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="./WizardStyle.xaml"/>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf;component/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.Dark.xaml" />
    <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf;component/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.Defaults.xaml" />
    <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignColors;component/Themes/Recommended/Primary/MaterialDesignColor.Blue.xaml" />
    <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignColors;component/Themes/Recommended/Accent/MaterialDesignColor.Blue.xaml" />

    <ResourceDictionary Source="./DataGridStyles.xaml"/>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="./TreeViewStyles.xaml"/>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="./ToggleButtonStyles.xaml"/>

    <ResourceDictionary>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGrid}" BasedOn="{StaticResource MaterialDesignDataGrid}">
            <Setter Property="AutoGenerateColumns" Value="False" />
            <Setter Property="CanUserAddRows" Value="False" />
            <Setter Property="CanUserDeleteRows" Value="False" />
            <Setter Property="SelectionMode" Value="Single" />
        </Style>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
```

Note that *MaterialDesignDataGrid* is defined inside MaterialDesignTheme.Defaults.xaml.

Is it an expected behavior? Am I doing something wrong?

Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: did you try with `DynamicResource` instead of `StaticResource`?

Comment: If you mean `<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGrid}" BasedOn="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignDataGrid}">`, yes, I did, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try different settings for the build action of your DataGridStyles.xaml. I think it should work if you set it to Page.

Comment: Connell, could it be an issue related to the order in which ResourceDictionaries are merged together.